# A problem on second order differentiation

Tags: derivatives

If $y=\sin x$, then find the value of $$\frac{d^2(\cos^7 x)}{dy^2}$$

I have no idea on how to proceed in this problem. Please help.

Comment: You can use the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dz}$. Then do another differentiation to derive a chain rule in the 2nd order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** notice that

$$ \cos x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also start replacing x by ArcSin[y] and remember that Cos[ArcSin[z]]=Sqrt[1-z^2]. Can you continue with this ?